# Error when requesting page with requests.get python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

i am trying to get html of supreme main page to parse it.
Here is what i am trying:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

all_page = requests.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/index', headers = {
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
    }).text
all_page_html = BeautifulSoup(all_page,'html.parser')
print(all_page_html)
```

But instead of html i get this response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/><title>Supreme</title><meta content="Supreme. The official website of Supreme. EST 1994. NYC." name="description"/><meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection"/><meta content="on" http-equiv="cleartype"/><meta content="notranslate" name="google"/><meta content="app-id=664573705" name="apple-itunes-app"/><link href="//www.google-analytics.com" rel="dns-prefetch"/><link href="//ssl.google-analytics.com" rel="dns-prefetch"/><link href="//d2flb1n945r21v.cloudfront.net" rel="dns-prefetch"/><script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js">async defer</script><meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" id="viewport" name="viewport"/><link href="//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/assets/application-2000eb9ad53eb6df5a7d0fd8c85c0c03.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet"/><script \
e.t.c
```

Is this a kind of a block or maybe i am missing something? I even added requested headers but still i get this type of response instead of a normal one.

Comment: It says `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<html ...>` so I would say that it *is* HTML.

Comment: but check the html code of the needed page it is different

Comment: what is the error in this?

Comment: not error, i mean it returns another thing

Comment: If I open `https://www.supremenewyork.com/index` in my web browser and look at the page source, I get exactly what you have shown in the question.

Comment: eventually it is not...try running this script

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's actually how the page is. It is saying that it's and HTML page with some css and javascript running, then you should use the "Inspect Element" to search for the elements you want to grab and maybe write down the class they are stored in to find them more easily.